# Sauvola Local Threesholding Function Error Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I´m working on a Image Binarization Algoritm that manually applies the Sauvola Local Threesholding. My code is the next one.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

def main():
    #Original
    img = cv2.imread('Lenna.png')
    cv2.imshow('Original',img)

    #IMG Gray
    imgg = gray(img)
    cv2.imshow('Gray', imgg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    #VALUES
    r = 128
    k = 0.5 
    w = 256

    sauvola(imgg,r,k,w)

def sauvola(im,r,k,w):
    rows, columns = im.shape[0], im.shape[1]

    pixels = np.zeros((rows,columns,3), dtype=np.uint8)
    x = w/2

    for i in range(rows-1):
        for j in range(columns-1):
            crop = im[i:w,j:w]
            img = np.array(crop)
            #Local Sauvola Formula
            pixels[i,j] = (np.mean(img) * (1+k*(np.std(img)/r-1)))
            x = x +1
            if(x > rows):
                x = w

def gray(img):
    channel = img.shape[2]
    if (channel > 1):
        g_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        return(g_img)
    else:
        return(img)


#MAIN
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I use the two `for loops` to create a W*W window and move it throught all the image to generate the new pixel for the filtered image.
When I try to run the code inside the `for loops` I get the next error

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3256: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:161: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:216: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  ret = _var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:185: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  arrmean = um.true_divide(
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:209: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

But the interesting part is that if I put that same instructions replacing i and j for any number between 0 and the window size (W) it works fine.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: Just a guess, in `crop=img[i:w, j:w]`... the error is coming when i or j > w... so change the range of i and j in the for loop. To check if this is only the reason, you can print values of i and j and see.

Comment: Btw these all are warnings you attached, what's the error.?